# How to hack Linux Netfilter-iptable?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I need to send packets and avoid Linux's monitoring/traffic concealing. How do I prevent the HOOK function before `net/netfilter/core.c nf_hook_slow()`? Some functions get NF_ACCEPT without these packets go into iptables.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: On Stack Overflow (and everywhere else you expect to be taken seriously) it is "you", not "u".

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as you might think it is - you would basically need a kernel module that

1. hooks the packet in very early stages (in `PREROUTING` chain) and marks the packet `NF_STOLEN`
2. route the packets yourself (which is **NOT** a trivial task) and
3. reinject them in the `POSTROUTING` chain with the correct ethernet headers inserted

In addition to this you would need to make sure that those chains will NOT drop the packet (I'm not sure if you can achieve this by having your hooks with topmost priority)